# What should I do when individual variables don't validate in a test set?

Tags: regression, validation

I built a model for purposes of prediction that validates out well overall on a test set. However, when looking at individual variables, there appears to be a couple (out of 100) that show no pattern. In other words, the patterns found in the development data seem likely to have been spurious. I'm now being criticized that my model is "bad" because it includes variables that can't be shown to be predictive on independent data and I'm not sure how to respond. For context, this is in a business setting and the person asking the question doesn't have a statistical background.

A few thoughts:

- I could just remove those variables and refit the model. I suppose there's nothing wrong with this necessarily. My test set would no longer be a test set since it was used to influence the model.
- I could do nothing. Isn't this basically why you use regularization? I have 1,000 variables and found 100 of them to have a pattern. Since I searched through so many variables, it's likely 1 or 2 of those patterns are fake, but I don't know which ones so I shrink all of them.
- What if the model was fit with stepwise selection? Is this a valid criticism then? I can't think of any real response in that case.

I understand the criticism in that it feels wrong to use a model that, after looking at the test set, appears to have some useless variables in it. Does anyone have any thoughts on how to respond?